# Extracting data from Abaqus .inp file

Tags: matlab, abaqus

I have created a mesh in abaqus. How can I open the .inp file in order to extract the node coordinate and node connectivity data?

Is there a way to convert it to a pdf or txt file?

Answer (score 1):

First, generate the .inp file by creating a job for your model and running 'write input'. Once you've done that, the .inp file is already just a text file. You can open it using a basic text editor, I would recommend something like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). The file will be organized by keywords indicated by an asterisk (*). To get the node coordinate and connectivity data look under the [*Node](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEKEYRefMap/simakey-r-node.htm) keyword (begins the section listing node numbers and coordinates) and the [*Element](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEKEYRefMap/simakey-r-element.htm) keyword (begins the section of element numbers and connectivity).